Can $\lfloor (4+\sqrt{11})^n \rfloor$ be described as a linear recurrence relation?
I ran into this problem while reviewing linear algebra and got stuck, I am out of prolific ideas to convert $x_n= \lfloor (4+\sqrt{11})^n \rfloor$ into some characteristic polynomial of a recurrence relation. By the way, the problem requests that I prove $x_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence relation, not necessarily to come up with the recurrence's equation itself.

You may want to use the fact that $0<4-\sqrt{11}<1$.

This is A279269.  For a cleaner regression, you might want to add $1$ to each term.

Let $a_n=(4+\sqrt{11})^n, b_n=(4-\sqrt{11})^n$.  Because $4\pm \sqrt{11}$ are the roots to the equation $x^2-8x+5$, anything of the form both $r_n=\alpha a_n+\beta b_n$ will satisfy the recurrence $r_{n+1}=8r_n-5r_{n-1}$ (why?).  If we can show that $x_n$ is of this form, we will be done.  There will be a slight hiccup, but we will deal with it.
Our first observation is that $0<4-\sqrt{11}<1$, so $0<b_n<1$.  The second is that $a_n+b_n$ is a whole number, which can be seen by taking conjugates (sending $x+y\sqrt 5$ to $x-y\sqrt 5$), and seeing that it is its own conjugate, which means it must be a whole number.
Put together, this yields that $a_n+b_n=\lceil (4+\sqrt{11})^n\rceil$.  Unfortunately, we wanted the floor, not the ceiling.  But since the ceiling is simply one more than the floor, this yields
$$x_{n+1}+1=8(x_n +1)-5(x_{n-1} +1).$$
Rearranging, this becomes
$$x_{n+1}=8x_n-5x_{n-1}+2,$$
which is unfortunately not linear because of the $+2$.  This can be fixed, however, by finding a linear recurrence that both $x_n+1$ and $r_n=1$ both satisfy, because then $x_n=(x_n+1)-r_n$
The trick is that $(x^2-8x+5)(x-1)=0$ has roots $1$ and $4\pm \sqrt{11}$, and expanding out we get $x^3=9x^2-13x+5$, so $x_n=(4+\sqrt{11})^n+(4-\sqrt{11})^n-1^n$ satisfies $$x_{n+1}=9x_n-13x_{n-1}+5x_{n-2}.$$
